# Get list of occurrences + count in a model Django?

Tags: django

Imagine I have the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...other stuff...
    optional_first_name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

How would I go about writing a request that returns an array of the most popular names, in decreasing order of occurence, with their counts, while ignoring the empty names?

i.e. for a database with 13 Leslies, 8 Andys, 3 Aprils, 1 Ron and 18 people who haven't specified their name, the output would be:

[('leslie', 13), ('andy', 8), ('april', 3), ('ron', 1)]

The closest I can get is by doing the following:

```
q= Person.objects.all()
q.query.group_by=['optional_first_name']
q.query.add_count_column()
q.values_list('optional_first_name', flat= True)
```

But it's still not quite what I want.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After some digging, finally found out:

```py
from django.db.models import Count
Person.objects.values('optional_first_name').annotate(c=Count('optional_first_name')).order_by('-c')
```

Comment: You might also want to `.exclude(optional_first_name='')`

Comment: how to apply some filters to this query? like filter only names starting with 'A'

Comment: @KiranTelukunta Person.objects.filter(optional_first_name__startswith='A').values('optional_first_name').annotate(c=Count('optional_first_name')).order_by('-c')

Comment: @AksharRaaj your answer was what I needed. Thank you. But in my template, it returns this '<QuerySet [{'illnesses': 1, 'c': 4}]>'. Please how do I clean it up to return only '4' because that is the number I need in my template?

This is my code in views.py 'count_ebola = MedicalInfo.objects.filter(illnesses__name__exact='Malaria').values('illnesses').annotate(
        c=Count('illnesses'))'