# Django filter and get the whole record back when using a .values() column-based annotation

Tags: python, django

This may be a common query but I've struggled to find an answer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811891/2034487) to an earlier question gets me half-way using `.annotate()` and `Count` but I can't figure out how then to get the full record for the filtered results.

I'm working with undirected networks and would like to limit the query based on a subset of target nodes.

Sample model:

```
class Edges(Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    source = models.BigIntegerField()
    target = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I want to get a queryset of `Edges` where the `.target` exists within a list passed to `filter`. I then want to exclude any Edges where the source is not greater than a number (1 in the example below but may change).

Here's the query so far (parenthesis added just for better legibility):

```
(Edges.objects.filter(target__in=[1234,5678, 9012])
              .values('source')
              .annotate(source_count=Count("source"))
              .filter(source_count__gt=1)
)
```

This query just delivers the `source` and new `source_count` fields but I want the whole record (`id`, `source` and `target`) for the subset.

Should I be using this as a subquery or am I missing some obvious Django-foo?

Comment: Why not `.values('id', 'source', 'target')` ??

Comment: @nik_m I gave that a try, but it breaks the `.annotate` / `Count` operation and the queryset is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either

```
Edges.objects.filter(target__in=[1234,5678, 9012], source_count__gt=1)
             .annotate(source_count=Count('source'))
             .values('id', 'source', 'target', 'source_count')
```

to get only the values of `id`, `source`, `target` and `source_count`, or

```
Edges.objects.filter(target__in=[1234,5678, 9012], source_count__gt=1)
             .annotate(source_count=Count('source'))
```

to get a QuerySet of `Edges` instances, where not only you get the above values but you can call any methods you have defined on them (might be a db consuming, though).

Comment: Thanks @nik_m - I got excited that this could work but I don't think it will because the column `source_count` hasn't been annotated by the time the `.filter` operation is called.

Comment: Strange. I tested it locally and it works really nice. Have you tried it?